# Right or wrong question about holomorphic function on unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $K_3(0)$ be a disc with radius 3 around $0$ and $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc.
Let $f\in H(K_3(0))$. If $|f(z)| \geq 1 \quad \forall z\in \partial\mathbb{D}$ and $|f(0)|<1$, then exists $\alpha\in \mathbb{D}$ such as $f(\alpha)=0$
I would say this is wrong, but I can't proof it yet. First I would have thought to say, that $f\in \mathbb{D}$ then we could use the minima principle (maximum principle used on $\frac{1}{f}$, but it wouldn't work since it's not given, that f is necessarily rootless on $K_3(0)$.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: why not just use $1/f$ in the closed unit disc and apply the maximum principle to derive a contradiction if it is analytic, so $f$ indeed must have a zero there

Comment: @Conrad how would you secure it‘s even well defined? I can‘t seem to follow your thoughts.

Comment: if $f$ has no zeros in the unit disc, then $g=1/f$ is analytic there, continuous on the closed unit disc, and $|g(0)| > g(z), |z| =1$ which is not possible by maximum modulus; what happens outside the unit disc is not really relevant for the problem here